# Windows: Find String Next Line

Tags: findstr

I am not good in Windows, and asking the master here.

I have a file which contains:

Line x: abc
Line x+1: def

I need to find the strings of abc and def and return as out output. Thanks

And limited to x line and x+1 line. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see you already found the "findstr" command in Windows, but unfortunately, the "findstr" command does not support to print the next (or previous) lines of the match.

You could use PowerShell ["Select-String"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1#example-8--find-lines-before-and-after-a-match) with "-Context" parameter.

E.g: Your file "test.txt" has: Line x: abc Line x+1: def

To print:

```
abc
def
```

as the output, you could use following command with PowerShell:

```
Get-Content test.txt | Select-String -Pattern abc -Context 0,1
```